# Writing Methods in Python 3 - Animal classification

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to build a class describing an unknown race (called `AnimalX`) of extinct animals. 
Each `AnimalX` may or may not have horns.

Thus far, I have written the following code:

```
class AnimalX
    """Defines the AnimalX class.
       Data attributes: name of type str
                     height (metres) of type float
                     has_horns of type bool    
    """

    def __init__(self, name, height, has_horns=False):
        """AnimalX constructor"""
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.has_horns = has_horns
```

This is to make sure that when we don't supply an argument for the `has_horns` parameter when instantiating an `AnimalX` object, its has_horns attribute is automatically set to `False`.

Using the `AnimalX` class I need to write two methods:

```
   say_hello(): it prints "Hi! The name is {name}!.
```

If the AnimalX has horns, print in all caps

```
   say_hello(): it prints "HI! THE NAME IS {NAME}
```

I have a basic understanding how to write methods, but the above is driving me crazy... I need advice on how to write the two methods above.

```
 Test Case:                                       Output
  first_AnimalX = AnimalX("Jeff", 1.6)
  first_AnimalX.say_hello()                    Hi! My name is Jeff!
```

Comment: What code have you write thus far for the `say_hello` method? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: You should definitely update the question with your first try at the `say_hello()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired behavior by writing just one method:

```
def say_hello(self):
    phrase = 'Hi! The name is ' + self.name + '!'
    print(phrase.upper() if self.has_horns else phrase)
```

I guess the absence of `'!'` at the end of all caps string in question was a typo. If not, use `phrase.upper()[:-1]`